# reverse configuring LDAP

Tags: java, apache, ldap

**uid=SOMEID,ou=people,o=my_bank**

is the DN I have in a properties file and is the user that should authenticate on LDAP also.
Since I have to troubleshoot a software from a bank I'm working for and to have the LDIF from server will be unpractical, not to say impossible, how can I setup my **Apache DS LDAP** to answer to this DN on authentication?

I have tryied diferent layouts for it but I'm always getting

***javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for uid=SOMEID,ou=people,o=my_bank]***

Comment: I do not understand. Where did that DN come from, if it isn't already in LDAP?

Comment: it's from a properties file. it's must be on LDAP, The case is that I running my own LDAP on dev and I don't know the way it was configured on the original one. I'm trying to guess it, but the problem is that I can only put a organization below a dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toplevel object in ApacheDS is called a partition. These cannot be created over LDAP, but have to be defined in the `server.xml` configuration file.

Find that file, open it and find the `<partitions>` section. There you can add a new one, and also choose the object class. Yours should be like this:

```
 <jdbmPartition id="my_bank" cacheSize="100" suffix="o=my_bank" optimizerEnabled="true"
                 syncOnWrite="true">
```

You can copy the `<indexedAttributes>` section of the other partition if you like. For a dev environment this is not super-important.